# Android Studio Change Fragment on Button Click

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Basically I have two fragments with two classes for each and one main class and main activity. I want to set one of the fragment as the home screen and when I press a button it shows the other fragment and hides the previous one.

Problems:
My first problem is that the application is not even opening, its saying,"Unfortunately Application stopped working".
Next, when I click on my button both the fragments are merging and the last fragment is not disappearing.

My main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    UpcomingProject Upcoming = new UpcomingProject();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, Upcoming);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {


}
```

My Main Activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/upcomingproject"/>
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/createproject"/>




</LinearLayout>
```

My Home page fragment xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_create"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:text="@string/button_create"
    android:layout_margin="15sp"
    android:background="@drawable/drawable_buttoncreate"
    android:clickable="true" />




</LinearLayout>
```

My home page fragment java class:

```
public class UpcomingProject extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView;
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.upcomingproject, container, false);
    Button CreateP = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_create);
    CreateP.setOnClickListener(this);

    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    CreateProject Create = new CreateProject();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, Create);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
}
```

My second fragment, the one I want to switch too on the click of a button:

```
public class CreateProject extends Fragment {



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView;
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.createproject, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
}
```

And the second fragment's xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/name_input"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/name_input"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/contact_input"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/contact_input"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/contact_description"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="@string/contact_description"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/email_input"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/email_input"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/email_description"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"


            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/category_input"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/category_input"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >


            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_individual"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/radio_individual"
                />

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_NPO"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/radio_NPO"
                />

            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_NGO"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/radio_NGO"
                />

        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/title_input"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/title_input"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/title_description"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:inputType="text" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/description_input"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/description_input"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_description"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:hint="@string/edit_description" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <Button android:id="@+id/button_register"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_register"
            android:layout_margin="10sp"

            android:background="@drawable/drawable_buttoncreate"/>

        <Button android:id="@+id/button_reset"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_reset"
            android:layout_margin="10sp"
            android:background="@drawable/drawable_buttoncreate"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: read about fragments [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Creating-and-Using-Fragments) and you will come up with a solution

Comment: try .add instead of .replace and the fragments won t merge

Comment: have you manifested everything in `manifest` file

Comment: @MarcinDeszczynski I tried didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `getSupportFragmentManager()` in your Main Activity to replace first fragment. And `getChildFragmentManager()` when you replace second fragment

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late reply, but I'll give it in case anyone else hits the same issue.
The reason for this problem was that you have explicitly defined the fragment in your xml file. If you want to swap the fragment it's best to define it as a FrameLayout and then swap it in your onCreate method using e.g.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FragmentTransaction fts = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fts.add(R.id.content, UpcomingProject.newInstance());
    fts.commit();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
This is all explained very well and in much more detail in the link in hrskrs's comment above (https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Creating-and-Using-Fragments)
```